# Attachments QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server, attachments

I was wondering if there in QGIS is a good tool for adding attachments to different layers. I have previously worked a lot with ArcMap and it has great attachment facilities. I haven't so far been able to find the same functionality in QGIS.

I have looked a bit on photo2kmz, but it only works with photos (I would also like to attach pdf files and/or word documents) and as I understand it it creates a new feature each time (I wish to attach photos and documents to existing features).

I have also looked at the possibility of making fields in attribute tables as "External resource" format, but here I only get the possibility of storing a path, that is not "click-able" so that I have to afterwards copy paste it into Windows Explorer.

Perhaps someone has a better solution for attaching photos, pdfs etc. to already existing layers preferably in a MSSQL environment.

Answer (score 3):

You document path is clickable if you use the action tool.

[image]

If you press the Add default action button, you get a sample of action. Try the Open file action where PATH is the column name of the field containing the path.

Comment: Hej Jakob. Thank you for your comment. That helped me some of the way, but I was hoping that there was a possibility of connecting my layer (or an attribute) to another table in MSSQl hosting the attachments. So that I would have an environment like the attachment functionality in ArcGIS.